# If $\frac{a+1}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer then it is $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, vieta-jumping

If $\frac{a+1}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer for positive integers $a,b$ then prove that this integer is $3$.

I reduced the to prove that if $\frac{c^2+d^2+1}{cd}$ is an integer then it is $3$ where $c,d\in{\mathbb{N}}$. And this is equivalent to prove that the Pell's equation $x^2-(k^2-4)y^2=-4$ has solutions for $k=3$ only. But I dont know how to prove it.

Comment: The arithmetic on your reduction looks wrong to me...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Can you state the correct one??

Comment: Correct is $(a^2+b^2+a)/(ab)$

Comment: if the result is 3 then b>1.

Comment: or $b=1$ (if a also is 1)

Comment: yes @turkeyhundt

Comment: This is a surprisingly subtle problem!  It's straightforward to show that $a\mid b^2$ and $b\mid a(a+1)$, and the former of course implies that every prime factor of $a$ is a factor of $b$, but it's actually straightforward to find pairs $a\neq b$ that satisfy these conditions but don't produce an integer sum - consider $a=8, b=12$ or $a=9, b=6$...

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria: Don't know if it helps, but I get the Pell's equation $x^2-(k^2-4)y^2=+4$.

Comment: I have this General formula. What she not good enough?  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046841___

Answer (score 3):

(The following answer  is quite similar to the one given by @math110, but I 
realized that only after arriving at my solution independently.
My formulation and the minimality condition is slightly different, so that I hope that it deserves
a separate answer.)

For fixed $k \in \mathbb N$, define the set of all solutions to 
$\frac{a+1}{b}+\frac{b}{a} = k$ as
$$
    S := \{ (a, b) \in \mathbb N^2 \mid a^2 + a + b^2 = kab \} \, .
$$

We want to proof that if $S$ is not empty then $k = 3$.

The proof is based on the following observations (similar to the
["Vieta Root Jumping"](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/vieta-root-jumping-2/) method):

- (i) If $(a, b) \in S$ then $(b^2/a, b) \in S$.
- (ii) If $(a, b) \in S$ then $(a, (a^2+a)/b) \in S$.

Proof of (i): $a$ is a solution of the quadratic equation
$$
   P(x) = x^2 - (kb-1)x + b^2 = 0 \, .
$$
It follows from Vieta's formulas that $a' = kb-1 -a \in \mathbb Z$ is the
other solution, and $aa' = b^2$, so that actually $a' \in \mathbb N$.
Therefore $(a', b) \in S$.

The proof of (ii) is the same, now considering $b$ as a solution of the quadratic equation
$$
   Q(y) = y^2 - (ka) y + (a^2 + a) = 0 \, .
$$

*Finally we prove:* If $S$ is not empty then $k = 3$.

The set $\{ a + b \mid (a, b) \in S \}$ is a non-empty set of positive
integers and therefore has a minimal element. Let $(a, b) \in S$ be such that $a + b$ is *minimal*.

*Case 1:* $a > b$. Then $a' = b^2/a < b < a$. From (i) we know that $(a', b)\in S$.
But $a' + b < a + b$ in contradiction to the minimality, so this case
cannot happen.

*Case 2:* $a < b$. Then $b' = (a^2+a)/b \le (a^2+a)/(a+1) = a < b$.
From (ii) we know that $(a, b') \in S$.
But $a + b' < a +b $ again in contradiction to the minimality, so this case
can also not happen.

That leaves us with *Case 3:* $a = b$. From
$$
  k = \frac{a+1}{b}+\frac{b}{a} = 2 + \frac 1b
$$
it follows that $b = 1$ and therefore $k = 3$ and we are done.

*Remark:* The proof has shown that if we start with an arbitrary solution $(a, b) \in S$
and apply the transformations (i), (ii) alternatingly, then we get a
sequence of solutions
$$
  (a, b) = (a_0, b_0), (a_1, b_1), \ldots (a_{n-1}, b_{n-1}), (a_n, b_n) = (1,1)
$$
where alternatingly $a_i < b_i$ or $a_i > b_i$ as long as $i < n$.

Since the transformations (i) and (ii) are self-inverse,
we can reverse the process to get *all* solutions iteratively
by starting with $(1,1)$ and then applying  (i) and (ii) alternatingly.
This gives the solutions
$$
  (1, 1), (1, 2), (4, 2), (4, 10), (25, 10), (25, 65), \ldots
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\dfrac{a^2+a+b^2}{ab}=k,k\in N^{+}$$
so
$$b^2-ka\cdot b+a^2+a=0$$
**case 1**

if $a\le b$ and $b$ is minimum

Now Assmue that  $b>a$,
then $b_{1}=ka-b\in Z$,and 
$$b\cdot b_{1}=a^2+a$$
so $b_{1}$ is postive integer number.
then
$$b_{1}=\dfrac{a^2+a}{b}<\dfrac{a^2+a}{a}=a+1$$ 
since $b_{1}>b\ge a+1$ impossible.

so $a=b$
then
$$a^2|(2a^2+a)\Longrightarrow a^2|a$$ then we have
$a=1,b=1$
so 
$$k=3$$

**case 2**: if $a\ge b$,then we consider
$$a^2+(1-kb)a+b^2=0$$

Now Assmue that $a>b$,and $a$ is minimum 
and 
$$a_{1}+a=kb-1\in Z,aa_{1}=b^2$$
then
$$a_{1}=\dfrac{b^2}{a}<b$$
impossible.

so $a=b$,then following is same as case 1

Comment: Why is $a\leq b$ WLOG? the two don't appear symmetrically in the original equation...

Comment: Hello,I have edit it

Comment: I don't get it after $\;b_1<a+1\;$ . You wrote "since $\;b_1>b...\;$" Why is this true? I mean, why $\;b_1:=ka-b>b\;$ ? This is true if $\;2b<ka\;$ . Why would this be true?

Comment: $b$ is minimum of solution

Comment: Yes, but: $b_1$ may be _labeled_ as a '$b$', but that doesn't mean it's a solution of the original equation. I also don't see why $b_1$ must be greater than $b$.